# How to join two classes in one list?

Tags: c#

I have this situation:

```
List<Details> trace; 
private class Details
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string mex { get; set; }
}
private class Context
{
    public List<object> context { get; set; }
}
```

how can I insert in the `trace` list the class `Details` and `Context`? My goal is create a multidimensional list that have as key the class properties such as: `date, type, mex, context` and as value a dynamic content.

Comment: Unless they implement the same base class/interface, this is a horrible idea.  What would happen if somebody iterating your list tried to access a `context` property of a `Details` object?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  At this point, I would say you should create an aggregate class which contains instances of both `Details` and `Context`, but I can't really say that for sure without a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by a multidimensional list, because the concept of multiple dimensions does not go well with inherently flat lists.

Comment: `List<object>` is an obvious option to hold either `Details` or `Context`. Then each item has to be cast (either `is` or `as`+`null` check).

Comment: @roryap Details contains the information about a stack trace, this class save more trace so usually I use a IDictionary. Instead, Context, is a list of context for the stack trace, so a trace could have more Context in it. I want to use a more readable object instead of the Dictionary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight something like: `date => 12/04/2016` (a list of date). This for each key of the list. So `date` is the key name, and the content is `12/04/2016`

Comment: Why not create a single class that encapsulates Details and Context?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli 'cause this class is for deserialize a json, so if I create a wrapper class I'll have a redundancy code.

Comment: How about `List<Tuple<Details, Context>>`?

Comment: @Sinatr should I save this declaration in other variable? I'm interested in your answer, could you explain a bit?

Comment: @Sandokan, I think the best way is modeling your classes according to your business (using wrapper class, whatever), most projects I've worked we create a class just to deserialize json, and then translate it to model class.

Answer (score 5):

You can use for that purpose an abstraction contract between both classes...
for example if both classes implement a new interface, lets say **MyCustomInterface** that you define, then declare the list as `List<MyCustomInterface> trace;` and then you can add objects of both classes...

## Example:

```
 List<MyCustomInterface> trace; 

    private class Details: MyCustomInterface
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string mex { get; set; }
    }

    private class Context:MyCustomInterface
    {
        public List<object> context { get; set; }
    }
```

then you can always do

```
trace.Add(new Context(...));
trace.Add(new Details(...));
```

Comment: Since there are no common things between the two classes, I can't see the benefit of using the interface. Why not use ```object```?

Comment: Seems a good workaround, but at this point I would know if I can achieve the same goal without create an Interface, maybe with another object, different by the list?

Comment: This answer lacks an example of how access items of such list (to demonstrate the problem of design).

Comment: if the OP considers to put both classes in the same list, they have for sure something in common that can be taken an abstraction level higher for the design....

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa, common? Only that they share same parent class - `object`. It would be a good extendable design if they would have anything in common. As for now `List<object>` will be better idea simply because you don't need to define empty `IMyCustomInterface`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Tuple<Details, Context>` to hold instance of either as item in the list, but then when iterating items you will then have to use `Item1` and such names to access underlying values:

```
List<Tuple<Details, Context>> trace; 

// add
trace.Add(new Tuple(new Details(), new Context()));

// iterate
foreach(var item in trace)
    if(item.Item1?.date == ... && item.Item2?.context != null) { ... }
```

A better idea might be to construct own type to hold both: `Details` and `Context` instance (as properties with same names):

```
class ContextDetails
{
    public Context { get; set; }
    public Details { get; set; }

    // todo: add constructor to simplify constructing items when adding
}
```

and use it

```
List<ContextDetails> trace; 

// add
trace.Add(new ContextDetails()
{
    Details = new Details(),
    Context = new Context(),
});

// iterate
foreach(var item in trace)
    if(item.Details?.date == ... && item.Context?.context != null) { ... }
```

Comment: Tuples are very rarely the best approach.  They're horrible to work with given the Item1....ItemN semantics.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm if you really wanted to have both in a List, i'd give you two options:

First:
Create a parent-Class which both inherit. 
Next step is to put the name of the parent class into your List.
Both will fit if they were extended by the same parent class

Second:
Create an Objekt that contains a Context and Details object and put that into the list.